# updating variable inside and outside struct, different results, why?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm, struct

With this, `bool p` does not update,

```
contract b {

        bool p;

    mapping(uint => bool) public t;

    function setValue() {
        bool b = t[1];
        b = true;
    }
    function checkValue() returns (bool) {
        return t[1];
    }
}
```

but with this, it does, why?

```
contract b {

    struct Info {
        bool p;

    }
    mapping(uint => Info) public t;

    function setValue() {
        Info b = t[1];
        b.p = true;
    }
    function checkValue() returns (bool) {
        return t[1].p;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an unfortunate aspect of the Solidity language. `Info b = t[1];` is implicitly the same as `Info storage b = t[1];`, so `b` is actually a pointer to the struct in storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that **bool** is a value type while **struct** is a reference type.

You can read more about the types in the Solidity documentation: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#reference-types

Answer (score 1):

In your first snippet, your line `bool b = t[1];` is retrieving a copy of t[1], because t[1] is a boolean primitive. It assigns it to a local variable b. Modifying `b` has no consequence on the values stored in `t`.

In your second snippet, your line `Info b = t[1];` retrieves a reference to t[1], because t[1] is a structure. The reference is assigns to b, and writing to `b.[field]` effectively modifies the fields of the structure.

The difference between value type and reference type is fundamental in computer languages, I suggest you read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type_and_reference_type

Answer (score 1):

Solidity has the concept of reference types and there are several of them such as dynamic arrays, fixed arrays, mappings and structs. You can read more about that here:
https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html

A struct is like a class of sorts where we have to create a new instance of it to use it.

This struct will have a couple of different fields that will describe its purpose for example:

```
contract Crowdfunding {
    struct Request {
       string description;
       uint value;
       address recipient;
       bool complete;
     }
}
```

Now a struct behaves differently than variables do, for example:

```
contract Crowdfunding {
    struct Request {
       string description;
       uint value;
       address recipient;
       bool complete;
     }

    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContribution;
    address[] public approvers;

    function Crowdfunding(uint minimum) public {
        manager = msg.sender;
        minimumContribution = minimum;
    }
}
```

Below the struct I have variables I created that I can access in a function, but a struct does not contain variables it contains reference types. So if you want to use the `Request` struct, then you have to create a new variable and say it is a type of `Request`.

So the above does not create an instance of a `Request` it just creates the idea of it or the type.

To actually create a request and have it stored inside the contract I will make an array that specifically holds variables of type request.

I am going to make a new array and specify its type is being request.

```
contract Crowdfunding {
    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
    }

    Request[] public requests;
    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContribution;
    address[] public approvers;

    function Crowdfunding(uint minimum) public {
        manager = msg.sender;
        minimumContribution = minimum;
    }
```

Notice I am using capital R because I used a capital R to define the struct. By convention we use capital for first letter when defining a struct which is dissimilar to how we do our other type definitions.

This variable of type `Request` is given the name `requests` and now anywhere in my contract I can make use of the `requests` array.

I could say `requests.push()` and push in a new request or give me the new requests in there with request index of zero like so: `requests[0]`.